# What does the ** maths operator do in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, operators

What does this mean in Python:

```
sock.recvfrom(2**16)
```

I know what sock is, and I get the gist of the `recvfrom` function, but what the heck is `2**16`? Specifically, the two asterisk/double asterisk operator?

---

*(english keywords, because it's hard to search for this: times-times star-star asterisk-asterisk double-times double-star double-asterisk operator)*

Comment: You can use `sock.recvfrom(1 << 16)`, you don't need to do a power operation for this

Answer (score 56):

It is the [power operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator).

From the Python 3 docs:

> The power operator has the same semantics as the built-in [pow()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#pow) function, when called with two arguments: it yields its left argument raised to the power of its right argument. The numeric arguments are first converted to a common type, and the result is of that type.

It is equivalent to 2<sup>16</sup> = 65536, or `pow(2, 16)`

Comment: Just for the record this is also the case in **Javascript** (since ECMAScript 2016 or ES7) too.  `Math.pow(2,16) === 2**16`
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33789331/225217

Answer (score 14):

http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions

```
a ** b  =  pow(a,b)
```

Answer (score 7):

2 raised to the 16th power

Answer (score 5):

I believe that's the [power operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator), such that `2**5` = 32.

Answer (score 1):

It is the awesome [power operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) which like [complex numbers](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#complex) is another thing you wonder why more programming languages don't have.