# JavaScript exponents

Tags: javascript, math

How do you do exponents in JavaScript?

Like how would you do 12^2?

Comment: [** operator is available in Chrome52, Edge14](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33789331/1090562)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There is an [exponentiation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Exponentiation_assignment), which is part of the ES7 final specification. It is supposed to work in a similar manner with python and matlab:

```
a**b // will rise a to the power b
```

Now it is already [implemented in Edge14, Chrome52](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-exponentiation_(**)_operator), and also it is available with traceur or babel.

Answer (score 136):

[`Math.pow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow):

```
js> Math.pow(12, 2)
144
```

Comment: When looking through the `Math` methods, I saw `exp`, and when that didn't work I just gave up. xD Should've gone a little further. Oh well. Thanks.

Comment: @tylermwashburn: exp(x) is the number e raised to the power x, that is, e^x. e = 2.71828182846...

Comment: Does somebody know where the name 'pow' comes from?

Comment: @steebchen: If you're asking about the origin of the name, it's short for "power", as in "two to the power of three". If you're asking which language introduced it as a function, It would probably be one of the first few ones in existence.

Answer (score 25):

[`Math.pow(base, exponent)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xhwcwy6%28v=vs.94%29.aspx), for starters.

Example:

```
Math.pow(12, 2)
```

Answer (score 10):

`Math.pow(x, y)` works fine for x^y and even evaluates the expression when y is not an integer. A piece of code not relying on `Math.pow` but that can only evaluate integer exponents is:

```
function exp(base, exponent) {
  exponent = Math.round(exponent);
  if (exponent == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (exponent < 0) {
    return 1 / exp(base, -exponent);
  }
  if (exponent > 0) {
    return base * exp(base, exponent - 1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working Example:

```js
var a = 10;
var b = 4;

console.log("Using Math.pow():", Math.pow(a,b)); // 10x10x10x10
console.log("Using ** operator:", a**b);  // 10x10x10x10
```

You can use either `Math.pow()` or `**` operator

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Using Math.pow
console.log(Math.pow(12, 2)); // 144
// Using ES7
console.log(12**2); // 144
// Using Recursion
const power =(base, exponent) => {
  if (exponent === 0) return 1;
  return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
}
console.log(power(12,2)); // 144
```

Answer (score -1):

**How we perform exponents in JavaScript**
*According to MDN*
The **exponentiation operator** returns the result of raising the first operand to the power second operand. That is, var1 var2, in the preceding statement, where var1 and var2 are variables. Exponentiation operator is right associative: a ** b ** c is equal to a ** (b ** c).
For example:
`2**3` // here 2 will multiply 3 times by 2 and the result will be 8.
`4**4` // here 4 will multiply 4 times by 4 and the result will be 256.

Answer (score -4):

Math.pow function is deprecated

```
Math.pow(a,b)
```

So better to use the exponentiation assignment ** as:

```
a**b
```

Example:

```
const postMoneyValuationRevenue = Math.round(
      exitValueRevenue / (1 + returnRatePercentage / 100) ** exitYear,
    );
```

Comment: Hi, the Same answer has already been accepted, I am sure your answer is the same as the previous answers nothing different, so you should always try to different answer from the previous one.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Math.pow is not deprecated at all. Check MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow