# while loop exceeding specified condition?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Program that calculates and shows the value of (2 to the 10th power)

This statement results in 1024.  I'm not understanding how it keeps looping after it reaches "9".  Does `"< 10"` mean loop around ten times, or loop up to a sum less than "10"?   Would appreciate someone explaining this to me.  Thanks!

```
var result = 1;
var counter = 0;
while (counter < 10) {
  result = result * 2;
  counter = counter + 1;
}
show(result);
```

Comment: unitl counter value is less than 10

Comment: A simple alert _should_ have been enough for you to realize what was going on. Debugging, it helps.

Comment: Consider adding a log statement or using the debugger when you're not sure of behavior.

Comment: Didn't add alert or console.log because I thought you guys would write whatever you wanted to run the code.

Comment: That isn't the attitude to have: You should always try to work things out yourself first before just jumping on here to ask... `Console.log(counter)`, or `alert(counter)` would have helped you work this out.

Comment: Argh, I know what the result is, phenom...  I ran it in a built-in js console.  The show() function is configured in this console app.  So I didn't have to write alert() or console.log().  At any rate, the comments dont answer my question.  Other people did.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907063/javascript-exponents

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your counter is running ten times, once each for the values 0-9.  When writing loops like that (that include a `<`) I think of the 10 as "this loop will be running ten times."  It's helped a lot with minor issues like this.

Remember, there are only two really hard things in programming: cache validation, variable substitution, and off-by-one errors.

Comment: All four of those problems always get me.

Answer (score 4):

```
loop 1: result = 1*2 (2) counter = 1
loop 2: result = 2*2 (4) counter = 2
loop 3: result = 4*2 (8) counter = 3
...
loop 10: result = 512*2 (1024)counter = 10
```

Comment: Thanks, Kevin.  I'm still learning javascript and it was great of you to dumb it down for me.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

It loops 10 times and as such it multiplies by two ten times and as such gives you 2^10 = 1024. Exactly.
P.S. If you only want this multiplication, you'd be better off with

```
result = 1 << 10
```

Comment: Thanks, Panda.  I'm going through an online tutorial and I needed more understanding on the solution code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes ten times 0 to 9 = 10.

When the compiler sees if 10 < 10 it evaluates to false.  If you want to see 10 change the condition to <=

Answer (score 2):

The program will only step inside the loop if the condition for the while-loop is met. So you check it *before* entering the loop.

If you want the program to step inside the loop one more time, either use a do-while loop where you check the condition *after* the execution of the loop.
You can also change the condition to "counter <= 10" and use the while-loop as is.

[Here](http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/while-loop.php) you can find more information on while-/do-while-loops and also breaks in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

When `counter` is 1 it `result` is 2^1
When `counter` is 2 it `result` is 2^2

Since `counter` is `10` at the end of the loop, `result` is `2^10`.