# Javascript math power real/irrational_number library

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, numbers, counting

I was looking all around the web, but could not find anything that helps me.

I need to do math: 10^(1.7), but javascript doesn't allow that. Can someone have sort of code or knows some library that could help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to use Math.pow()

It have been answered here...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907063/javascript-exponents

Comment: Also ^ is XOR in JavaScript to further add to your troubles. And may I add that if you found an answer among those offered it would be a nice thing to do to tick one of them. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm confused:

```
Math.pow(10,1.7)
```

will do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the power of a real number `base` to the power of `exponent` do:

```
Math.pow(base, exponent);
```

With the values you have it is

```
Math.pow(10, 1.7);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow for documentation

Comment: thank you, I was just having a problem because i named 10 as A1 and 1.7 as a A2, and then parsed int: `parseInt(A1); parseInt(A2);` and after after few hours realised that Math.pow(A1, A2) gives only Integer answer in that case.