# Why am I losing the decimal when working this equation in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, decimal, equation

I am working on a calculator to figure out how much of a substance is still in someones system after x amount of days. The three variables are the amount taken daily, the number of days it has been taken, and the half-life of the substance. My formula below may not be 100% correct, but that's not the problem I'm having at this time. 
I'm having problems with the answer being converted to an integer. Where am I going wrong? I need everything to stay with a float (decimal) value.

P.S. Ignore comments, they were just added on here to explain variables.

```
dose = 8.00  // 8mg dose

meta = 70.0  // 70 hour half-life

days = 5     // 5 days of use


sys = dose * (1.0/2.0) ^ (24.0/meta)


for(x=2; x <= days; x++){

    sys = ((sys+dose) * (1.0/2.0) ^ (24.0/meta))

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript exponents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907063/javascript-exponents)

Answer (score 6):

`^` in javascript isn't the mathematical 'raise to a power' operator, it is the bitwise XOR operator, and will always give a integer.  You want to use `pow` from the `Math` class.

Try

```
sys = dose*Math.pow((1.0/2.0), (24.0/meta))
```

and

```
sys = (sys+dose)*Math.pow((1.0/2.0), (24.0/meta))
```

instead

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, JavaScript automatically casts whole numbers to integers. Once it has a decimal value (other than 0), e.g. 1.5, it should respect the float.