# How can I write a multiplication in jquery in a better way?

Tags: jquery

How can I write this in jquery:

1024<sup>4</sup>

I wrote for example this and want to write it in an easier way:

```
 var number = $("#cal").val()*1024*1024*1024*1024;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907063/javascript-exponents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to multiply your number with 1024<sup>4</sup>, this should do:

```
var number = $('#cal').val() * Math.pow(1024, 4);
```

Btw, the math functionality here has nothing to do with jQuery. It is a part of the [Math library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) found in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a function `Math.pow` which can be used in this instance. So what that would look like with the code above is the following:

```
var number = $("#cal").val() * Math.pow( 1024, 4 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Math.pow()` 
See here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pow.asp

Answer (score 0):

in Javascript you have the Option:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.pow(4, 3);
}
</script>
```

Also see there: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pow.asp