# Javascript Exponents in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms, math, exponent

I need to create a JavaScript function that uses input=number to pass it to a JavaScript function to raise it to 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th powers. So far I can pass a number to it and out put that number, but can not seem to grasp the math.pow and also how to get all the other powers. Here is what I have so far.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Opponents!? More Like Ex-Ponents</h1>

<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="0">

<p>Click the button to get the exponents of the number field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;  
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm not able to just input values. I need to be able to take a value that was input by the user and do the calculations on it. I've tried this with little results.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
    var y = math.pow(x,2);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript exponents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907063/javascript-exponents)

Comment: X*X an X amount of times by loops?

Comment: Just use Math.pow(x, power). So x is your number that you inputted and power is what you want to raise it by.

Comment: And what does "Click the button to get the exponents of the number field." this mean? How can you "get" the exponents of any number, you need to "set" them.

Comment: I have a html input text field, I need to pass (set as a variable) what is typed in that field and then output what the power of each is.

Comment: @AndrewL thank you, that was what worked. Could not get Math.pow or Math.exp to work. Neither would take my variable, so I abandoned them. Sorry don't have enough juice here to up vote your answer. But wanted anyone else looking for this to know you helped. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Math.pow works like so:

```
Math.pow(value, exponent)
```

so if I wanted to raise 5 by 11 I would do:

```
Math.pow(5,11)
```

Just replace the numbers with the variables you're using for value and exponent