# Express A^2 as A * A in Matlab

Tags: matlab, substitution, exponent

So, I have a really long symbolic exrpression in Matlab that I want to copy/paste into a JavaScript-code to animate a numerical solution for it. The problem is that some places in my code i get exponents (mostly ^2), when I'd rather have Matlab express it as A*A.

I have mulitple (and different) expressions like

```
cos(th2t)^2
```

That I would rather have expressed as

```
cos(th2t)*cos(th2t)
```

Any way I can do this? The alternative is to use a text editor afterward and search for powers of 2 and replace it, but there are multiple different expressions, so that would take some time...

This is an example of one of the exrpressions I end up with:

```
(J31*(2*ddth2t*cos(th1t) - 2*w12*w13 - 4*dth1t*dth2t*sin(th1t) - 4*dth2t*w13*sin(th1t) + dth1t^2*sin(2*th2t)*cos(th1t) - w12^2*sin(2*th2t)*cos(th1t) + w13^2*sin(2*th2t)*cos(th1t) + 2*dth2t*w11*sin(2*th2t) + 2*w12*w13*cos(th2t)^2 + ddth1t*sin(2*th2t)*sin(th1t) + 4*dth1t*dth2t*cos(th2t)^2*sin(th1t) + 2*dth1t*w13*sin(2*th2t)*cos(th1t) + 4*dth2t*w13*cos(th2t)^2*sin(th1t) + w11*w12*sin(2*th2t)*sin(th1t) + 4*dth1t*w12*cos(th1t)^2*cos(th2t)^2 - 2*dth1t*w11*sin(2*th1t)*cos(th2t)^2 - 2*dth2t*w11*sin(2*th2t)*cos(th1t)^2 + 2*w12*w13*cos(th1t)^2*cos(th2t)^2 - w11*w13*sin(2*th1t)*cos(th2t)^2 - 4*dth2t*w12*cos(th1t)*cos(th2t)*sin(th1t)*sin(th2t)))/(2*(J11 + J31))
```

Comment: Write a [`regexp`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to detect `^` , and substitute the expression before that as many times as the power behind it. (I can't regexp, so I can't help you there).

Comment: @Adriaan that might work. I'm not got with regexp either, so it would probably be faster for me to just hard code the changes is a text editor...

Comment: `syms th2t ;`  `factor(cos(th2t)^2)`

Comment: @SardarUsama I editet my question.  The expressions I end up with are too long for me to read through, and not all of them have exponents. In an expression like a +b * c + d * e^2 + f, I want to change it to just a +b * c + d * e*e + f

Comment: Could try `A**2` a comment on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5907063/5358968) suggests it works in some browsers

Comment: @Steve It worked! I just copy/paste the equations through a text editor and replaced all cases of ' ^ ' with  ' ** ' , and it run in both Chrome and Firefox. It does the trick for my silly problems, though it's not the ideal solution.

Comment: A regexp might also work for simple cases, but it would get a bit more tricky if it had to parse something like `cos(x^2+2*y)^2` or a fractional exponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve's answer should work fine if you want to rely on the ** operator. However, since that operator is not officially supported, and that solution doesn't directly answer the OP's question, here is a function that can expand out the exponents in a symbolic expression.

```
function [ text ] = remove_powers( exp )
%Cleans the powers from T, and return expanded text representation

    % Define functions
    enclose =@(t) ['(' t ')'];
    expand_pow=@(b,p) strjoin(strcat(cell(1,p),enclose(char(b))),'*');
    count_pow=@(s) arrayfun(@(k) count(char(s(k)),'^'), 1:length(s));
    sym2str = @(s) strrep(char(s), ' ', '');

    % Check for fractions
    [N,D]=numden(exp);
    if ~isequal(D,sym(1))
        % pass up the num and den
        text = [remove_powers(N) '/' enclose(remove_powers(D))];
    else
        % Split a into subterms
        Ts = children(exp);

        % Clean children
        has_pow=count_pow(Ts)>0;
        text = sym2str(exp);
        if sum(count_pow(Ts))<count_pow(exp)
            % We have removed a power, clean it, expand it, and pass up
            text = expand_pow(remove_powers(Ts(1)),Ts(2));
        else
            % Just clean the unclean children and pass up
            for t=Ts(has_pow)
                text = strrep(text,sym2str(t),remove_powers(t));
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The function uses the [`children`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/children.html) function in Matlab to recursively clean each subexpression and replace it (as text) in the parent. This method is better than using regex because it avoids the issue of parsing the syntax, as Steve mentioned in the comment with respect to `cos(x^2+2*y)^2`.

Which makes for a good example:

```
syms x y real
exp = cos(x^2+2*y)^2;
cleaned_exp = remove_powers(exp)
```

Outputs: `(cos(2*y+(x)*(x)))*(cos(2*y+(x)*(x)))`

Notice that since Matlab is doing the parsing, there was no need to parse the order of precedence for the '^' operators, which could be difficult to accomplish with regex.

To test the OP's example:

```
syms ddth1t dth1t th1t ddth2t dth2t th2t w11 w12 w13 J11 J31 real
exp = (J31*(2*ddth2t*cos(th1t) - 2*w12*w13 - 4*dth1t*dth2t*sin(th1t) - 4*dth2t*w13*sin(th1t) + dth1t^2*sin(2*th2t)*cos(th1t) - w12^2*sin(2*th2t)*cos(th1t) + w13^2*sin(2*th2t)*cos(th1t) + 2*dth2t*w11*sin(2*th2t) + 2*w12*w13*cos(th2t)^2 + ddth1t*sin(2*th2t)*sin(th1t) + 4*dth1t*dth2t*cos(th2t)^2*sin(th1t) + 2*dth1t*w13*sin(2*th2t)*cos(th1t) + 4*dth2t*w13*cos(th2t)^2*sin(th1t) + w11*w12*sin(2*th2t)*sin(th1t) + 4*dth1t*w12*cos(th1t)^2*cos(th2t)^2 - 2*dth1t*w11*sin(2*th1t)*cos(th2t)^2 - 2*dth2t*w11*sin(2*th2t)*cos(th1t)^2 + 2*w12*w13*cos(th1t)^2*cos(th2t)^2 - w11*w13*sin(2*th1t)*cos(th2t)^2 - 4*dth2t*w12*cos(th1t)*cos(th2t)*sin(th1t)*sin(th2t)))/(2*(J11 + J31));

cleaned_exp = remove_powers(exp);
isequal(sym(cleaned_exp),exp)   % This should be 1
count(cleaned_exp,'^')          % This should be 0
```

As expected, the new expression is equivalent to the original, but has no '^' symbols.

Comment: This is really impressive!
Thank you for all the work you've put into this. I hope this can help someone else than me too.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33789331/5358968) suggests that you could call the exponential operator in Javascript with e.g. `A**2`. As such you could replace all instances of `^` with `**`.
(Solution from comments)

Comment: I think regexp would be the best way, but this worked just fine for me.

Comment: @AndreasEvjenth this simple solution can be achieved with a [`strrep`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) I think. Then at least it can be automated, and, as Steve pointed out in the comments, you don't have to worry about fractional components. I.e. `NewFunc = strrep(OldFunc,'^','**');`