# JavaScript get exponentation of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I have an array:
`[2,3,4]`
I need the result, 2 to the power of 3 to the power of 4
and the result is 4096. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907063/javascript-exponents)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a one-liner with ECMAScript6:

```
array.reduce( (total, cur) => total**cur );
```

And if you really don't want to use ECMAScript6:

```
array.reduce( function(total, cur) { return Math.pow(total, cur); } );
```

```js
const data = [2, 3, 4];

const exponentiateArray = array => array.reduce( (total, cur) => total**cur );

console.log(exponentiateArray(data)); // 4096
```

Comment: what is the **?

Comment: @red_script [the exponentiation operator](http://2ality.com/2016/02/exponentiation-operator.html) introduced in ES6.

Comment: @EternalDarkness The exponentiation operator was introduced in ECMAScript 2016/ES7. Not ES6.