# ** (times times) in Python

Tags: python, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the ** operator do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683008/what-does-the-operator-do-in-python)

What does the ** do/mean in following python code?

```
range(2,int(startnumber**0.5)+1)
```

I was working with some Fibonacci numbers and fell over the function on the internet. Can't seem to find it in the documentation

Comment: See `help('**')` (if in danger or in doubt, `help()`!)

Comment: When in doubt fire up the python console and try: `2**3 == 8`. I don't want to sound aggressive but if you search for python operators, this is the first result: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex It clearly explains all the operators. Stack overflow is not a replacement for Google.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means "to the power of."  So `x**2` means x squared, and `x**0.5` means the square root of x.

Comment: Or, more usefully for the OP: `x**0.5` means the square root of `x`.

Comment: You must have typed that at the same time as me!