# complicated variable assignment

Tags: python

I usually  do my incrementation this way:

```
n=0
n=n+1 # and never do n+=1
```

Now there is code that I am trying to comprehend and I'm struggling to understand it.

```
sum=0
temp = num
while temp > 0:
    digit = temp % 10
    # below is the line I do not understand
    sum += digit ** power # what is happening here?. with power= len(str(num))
    temp //= 10

if num == sum:
   print num
```

This snippet is a piece to list the armstrong numbers.

Comment: In your case (and most cases), the line `sum += digit ** power` is equivalent to `sum = sum + digit ** power`.

Comment: Please provide the complete code. Also, `num` is not defined, please explain what `num` is.

Comment: @Flaming_Dorito the OP isn't asking to debug code, they're asking for someone to explain what `n ** x` means. Thus, an MCVe isn't necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the \*\* maths operator do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683008/what-does-the-maths-operator-do-in-python)

Comment: @ResetACK OP might have been asking why we do that calculation and what it means in the calculation of the final answer. It wasn't clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python `**` is the sign for exponent, so `x ** 2` is `x^2` (or x squared).

`x += g` is the same as `x = x + g`

`sum += digit ** power` == `sum = sum + (digit ** power)`

Comment: As for being reluctant to use `n += 1`, it's up to you but that method is far easier to understand in my opinion than `n = n + 1`

Answer (score 2):

```
while temp > 0:
    digit = temp % 10 
    sum += digit ** power
    temp //= 10
```

1. Take the last digit of `temp`
2. Add to `sum` the `digit` to the power of `power`
3. Delete the last digit of `temp`

Answer (score 0):

suppose `num = 34`, then `power` becomes `2`, so, for first iteration:

```
digit = 4
sum = 0 + 4 ** 2 # which is 0 + 16 = 16. Then adding to sum
```

so, `digit ** power` is `digit` to the power of `2`

similarly, for second iteration:

```
digit = 3
sum = 16 + 3 ** 2 # which is  16 + 9 = 25
```